# jquery ajax calls gives 404 for Windows phone

Tags: ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, http-status-code-404

I build my software with Jquery mobile. In my code I use Ajax JSONP calls to retrieve information from a server. This gives no problem when testing in my browser. With phonegap / cordova  I have generated an Android APK and a Windows XAP file. The Android build gives also a success, but when running on a Windows phone I get a 404 error.
Does anybody have a clue what could be the reason for this 404 error; could it have to do with permissions?
Many thanks in advance.

In the config.xml I have added: access origin="*"

The Ajax call looks like:

```
    function retrieveProvincies()
{
    $.ajax({url: 'http://www.itclubsupport.nl/test/AppPHPtest/AppIngang.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            indicatieTestenApp: 'yes',
            soortRequest: 'retrieveProvincies',
            klantnaam: 'klantITclubsupport'
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",

            success: function (response) {
                alert('works!');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                alert('Status ' + jqXHR.status + ' received when retrieving provincies. Error: ' 
                + textStatus  + '; ' + errorThrown);
            }
        })
    }
```